# check who can "sudo -u myaccount..."

Tags: linux, sudo

is there a way if owner of an unix account (no root) can check which of non-root users are allowed to run commands as he, using sudo?

/etc/sudoers is not readable.

For my personal safety I'd like to have possibility to check who is allowed use sudo to access my account.

for example if user A can run "sudo -u myaccount -i" or any command.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to list all the users, list that is readable for everyone at **/etc/passwd**; to have a clear list you could perform a:

```
cat /etc/passwd |cut -d : -f 1 > /tmp/userlist.txt
```

That would save all the users in */tmp/userlist.txt*, after that you can perform a simple script to check whether the user is sudoer or not as with the command **sudo -l -U username**, you can check if the user has those rights. For example you can do the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /etc/passwd |cut -d : -f 1 > /tmp/userlist.txt

while read line
do
        sudo -l -U $line
done < /tmp/userlist.txt

rm /tmp/userlist.txt
```

This would print if each user is sudoer or not and also which commands can perform.

Comment: What will happen, if accounts are managed via LDAP? :)

Comment: true, users come from ldap in my case, anyhow the proposed command (sudo -l -U user) is not working for non-root users which I am